# Android GCM not receiving messages when killing from task manager

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM push notifications for Android and I noticed that when I close the app from my Samsung Galaxy S3 task manager push notifications are not received anymore. The weird thing is that if I close the app by swiping it, it is also not visible anymore in the task manager but using the latter method I still receive the push notification.

Also, if I restart the phone I still receive it. However if I close the app and restart the phone I do not receive the push.

Does Android close more resources when closing the app from the task manager rather than by swiping? It is still strange however as when I restart the phone I am thinking that the app is still completely closed. Could it be that the Android system knows after a restart that it was not closed from the task manager?

I search a bit around this issue and from what I found it looks like closing it from the task manager should still enable you to receive the push notification. Only when force closing the app the notifications would not be received.

Any thoughts and workarounds maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Android close more resources when closing the app from the task manager rather than by swiping?

My guess is that whatever this "task manager" is on Samsung devices does the equivalent of "Force Stop" on your app's page in the list of apps in Settings. "Force Stop" basically nukes your app from orbit, moving into a "stopped" state. None of your app's manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers` will be invoked again -- including the one for GCM -- until the user launches your activity from the home screen (or, conceivably, something else manually runs one of your components).

> it looks like closing it from the task manager should still enable you to receive the push notification

There is no "task manager" in Android. Third-party task manager apps cannot do the equivalent of a "Force Stop". However, there is nothing stopping a *device manufacturer*, like Samsung, from implementing a task manager that does do the equivalent of a "Force Stop". IMHO, this was a bad move on their part, but they don't usually ask me for my opinion in advance of making engineering decisions... :-)

Comment: Now im remembering the days when I used to root the galaxy s2. There wasnt any task manager. However there was a game which I used to close and I used to receive weekly pushes. I am not 100% if I used to close it from the task manager though...